# Check if iPhone gets "tapped" on

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I wanted to know if there is a possibility to find out whether the iPhone gets "tapped" from the outside.

For example: You have it in your pocket and double tap on the outside of it. I know there is `CMMotionManager` but I couldn't figure out a way to use that data in order to reach my goal.

Does anyone have another answer ?

Comment: There is certainly apps that do this, [Knock](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/knock-unlock-your-mac-without-password-using-your-iphone/id692929970?mt=8) for instance. Maybe they use the microphone to listen for "knocks" that'll be incredibly loud compared to other background noise. Might be a creative approach :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint!